# What movie involves a boy feeding monsters underground?

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

This was an American movie I'm pretty sure made in the either late 80s or early 90s. I don't think the movie had any famous actors. The plot involves a kid bullied at school I think. Somehow, either through being chased or avoiding his usual trek home he happens upon a hole with a bunch of monsters under the ground. I think he thinks of them as his friends and decides to help them by feeding them. I think at first he feeds them fruit or something, but they hate it. So he feeds them meat.  At one point some of the bullies chase him and they fall into the hole. The monsters eat them I think. From this he starts feeding them people he hates.

At the same time this is going on he has a crush on his teacher. He finds out her boyfriend or husband is abusive. He then tries to lure the guy to the hole which I think works.  But somehow the teacher is also lured into the hole, I think by them imitating the young boy's voice, but this may be incorrect. They eat her, to which then the boy becomes angered with them, which in turn he says they need to fend for themselves and let them out. I don't remember what happens afterwards.  I think when you see the monsters, all you see is the glowing eyes.

Comment: Sounds very similar to Little Shop of Horrors

Comment: @sanpaco I am guessing it is definitely influenced by that movie.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like [The Pit](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086113/combined) (1981), though I'm pretty sure the kid has a crush on his *babysitter*.

> Twelve year-old Jamie Benjamin is a misunderstood lad. His classmates pick on him, his neighbors think he's weird and his parents ignore him. But now Jamie has a secret weapon: deep in the woods he has discovered a deep pit full of man-eating creatures he calls Trogs... and it isn't long before he gets an idea for getting revenge and feeding the Trogs in the process!

He also uses the hole to get rid of some bullies, and the creatures' eyes glow. When his babysitter falls down the hole too, Jamie gets upset and tells the Trogs they have to get by without his help. Here's the trailer:

Comment: I honestly forgot how messed up this movie really was, that kid was so much more messed up then I originally remembered. Do you remember this movie off the top of your head?

Comment: I did (barely). And yeah, that old woman in the wheelchair is a bit hard to stomach... Sorry. :P Glad you found it.